# DDD: Global unique identities vs surrogate

Tags: architecture, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design

Let's start with an example: we have an entity: `Book`. It has unique identity: `Isbn` - a value object that wraps a `String`. This is an UUID.

The `Book` entity also needs a surrogate id from the repo (sql db). We need it so we can e.g. find the books in faster way, since databases find by number faster then by string.

From what I read, the surrogate key should be hidden from the `Book`s interface. But we want to use it, to locate books much faster.

How to deal with this in a proper way?

**[A]** We can simply add a `getSurrogateId()` (or any better name) in the `Book`. This pollutes the entity, but its KISS.

**[B]** We can have the repo responsible for finding the surrogate keys for the natural ones. For example, `BookRepository` may have the following method:

```
long toSurrogateKey(Isbn isbn) {
     // lookup the cache
     // if not found, lookup the db
}
```

to return the surrogate key - of course, these values can be cached locally, so we do not need to search db every time. This method should not be `public` (right)?

**[C]** We can go even further: to think about surrogate key as a repository specific one. `Book` may be an interface, and `SqlBook` may be an repository-made implementation. This `SqlBook` implementation may then store any *additional* information needed for the repository. In this case, we would have the surrogate key as one of the properties of `SqlBook` - and we do not care it is visible, as users of `SqlBook` only sees it as a `Book`, i.e. not knowing about the surrogate id.

So above method becomes (defined in `SqlBook` class):

```
long toSurrogateKey(Book book) {
     return ((SqlBook)book).getSurrogateId();
}
```

The only drawback here is that `Book` (and other entities) must be created by a Factory that is repository-aware. In other words, we would need to have `SqlFactory` implementation of some factory that creates `SqlBook`s for us.

Any wisdom on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We need it so we can e.g. find the books in faster way, since databases find by number faster then by string.

Surrogate keys should primarily be added because they provide you a uniform way for building your primary keys, not because of any hypothetical performance issues. They will help you to avoid having business data like an Isbn distributed over half of your model in separate places because you misuse them as foreign keys.

> "From what I read, the surrogate key should be hidden from the Books
>   interface".

Maybe you just misunderstand the purpose of this? Surrogate keys are technical details which should be hidden when discussing the model with your domain experts, but it is perfectly ok to see them when you change your viewpoint to the implementation of the model. So go with [A], but make sure the `getSurrogateId()` accessor is not visible in your graphical form of your domain model.

Comment: Thanx! It's not hypothetical - it's implementation fact. But maybe it's not a 'surrogate key', I admit, just an 'additional technical/implementation information' of the `Book`. Anyway, I believe this is not just a matter of graphical visibility. The API should also express to developers the right usage. So if we expose this method as public one, developers may start using it for other stuff, instead of the real key. Then we do not need `Isbn` to be nothing more than just a simple value object. Any thought/experience?

Comment: Honestly, your fears sound superstitious to me. I work with "technical keys" instead of "business keys" since almost 20 years and from that experience I can tell you you should *encourage* your devs to use the technical primary key instead of a business key whereever possible. The less places you use the business key as a unique identifier, the less places you will have to change when something changes in your business key (which will happen).

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I also work with 'technical' keys all my life:) The focus here is not to have it working, but trying to figure the DDD concepts in practice. And the DDD says opposite, that we actually should use domain primary key in the code, too, as part of ubiquitous language.

Comment: @lawpert: can you give a reference where "DDD says that"? I guess that's just a misunderstanding or misinterpreation. IMHO the usage of keys should be: use business keys like an ISBN in code when you have to deal with the "business meaning" of that key (for example: a end-users search function), and you use the technical or surrogate key whenever you need a key for persistent object identity. Here is a short article http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/06/05/designing-primary-keys/ reflecting exactly what I think about it.

Comment: I think I am saying exactly the same: use business keys for domain talk, use tech key for underlaying persistence. But I also want to prevent to have developers choosing which one to use - from my point of view, that is dangerous in development environment. People may soon start using tech key for domain stuff. Therefore, the idea here is also to 'hide' the tech key until the place it is really used, in the repo/persistence. Would it make sense, in your opinion?

Comment: @lawpert: no, it does not make sense, and I believe you are overthinking this. You cannot give a reference "where DDD says devs should not access the surrogate", and I think you also cannot give a reason **why** you think it is dangerous to do so - still sounds just superstitious to me.

Comment: Reference: "It’s best to hide the surrogate attribute from the outside world. Because the surrogate is not part of the domain model, visibility constitutes persistence leakage." Page #186, "Implementing DDD" by V. Vernon. I do also experience improper use of the tech ids, that get inside almost all _application_ services.

Comment: @lawpert: Vernon probably means with "outside world" the viewpoint of your domain experts, not "the developers point of view".

Comment: He means outside the scope of that class. Like to set it `private`. The developers concern is added by me ;)

Comment: @lawpert: so as I suspected - just *your* interpretation. Try to interpret that part differently - problem solved.

Comment: Hey @Doc Brown, it's not like that. Vernon (and others as well) says that this kind of keys should be hidden from the interface. This is _not_ my interpretation. Now, I have _added_ additional 'developers' concern to this story (since I am having that problem) where developers have 'polluted' the system using technical key where it should not make sense. All what you are saying I do understand, but trying to figure if there is a better way, that could solve more real-life problems. So I am not fighting with you, I am just asking these questions myself as well.

Comment: If one uses a surrogate for performance reasons that clearly makes it a 'physical' key which must not be part of the domain model. On the other hand, if one uses a surrogate key because the natural key lacks stabililty, I wonder if that's not a logical problem and therefore the surrogate could be seen as part of the domain model. But I am not completely soure yet about this.